# How to test two datetimes for equality in T-SQL (ignoring their time components)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

How can I test two datetimes (not including their time components) for equality?

Comment: Do you mean "how can I test two dates (not including their time components) for equality?".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

For example to only compare the months:

> SELECT DATEDIFF(month, '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');

This is the best way to do comparisons and determine the differences based on your exact need for the query your doing. It even goes down to milisecond.

Answer (score 2):

```
DATEDIFF(day, rem.DueDate , GETDATE()) = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

To test if the two dates are equal, ignoring the time component:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, @first, @second) = 0
```

To test if the two times are equal, ignoring the date component:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(day, 0, @first), @first) =
    DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(day, 0, @second), @second)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
WHERE floor(convert(real,date1))=floor(convert(real,date2))
```