# Select keyword require > instead of =

Tags: asp.net, datarow

if i use    = instead of >  in  line below
  TextBox1.Text = "regdate > '12/12/2012 8:27:09'";

it return me zero rows . Any reason ?

```
        DataView dv1 = new DataView ();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet ();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        /*
         col1   col2            col3    col4            col5
         1      sw@yahoo.com    sw      Stephen Walther 12/12/2012 8:27:09 PM
         2      as@yahoo.com    as      Al Stevens      12/12/2012 8:27:09 PM
        */
```

// Here is the code and criteria for selecting few rows based on datetime .

```
        TextBox1.Text = "regdate > '12/12/2012'";

        //connection created 

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter ("SELECT * FROM users",con);
        da.Fill (ds);

        // filtering criteria applied .
        DataRow[] dr = ds.Tables["Table"].Select(TextBox1.Text);

         //columns created
        dt.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("col3", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("col4", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("col5", typeof(DateTime));

         // data added
        foreach (DataRow item in dr)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(item.ItemArray);
        }

        // view created
        dv1 = dt.DefaultView ;
        GridView1.DataSourceID = string.Empty; 
        GridView1.DataSource = dv1 ;
        Page.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the time component is stopping the match - it is trying to match the date AND time.

You could try to use some kind of DATEDIFF function to just match the date portion

[How to test two datetimes for equality in T-SQL (ignoring their time components)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437921/how-to-test-two-datetimes-for-equality-in-t-sql-ignoring-their-time-components)

BUT - when amending the code just be really careful with this - not to start putting text box input into the SQL statement. Injection attack risk aplenty.

I think you are OK as it stands but....

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a datetime field, so it will compare the whole date and time value, not just the date.

The value `12/12/2012 8:27:09 PM` and `12/12/2012` are not the same, because the `12/12/2012` gets expanded to the `12/12/2012 12:00:00 AM` value to be comparable to the datetime value. The datetime value doesn't get truncated to be comparable to the date value.

Generally when data types doesn't match for a comparison or calculation, the smaller type gets expanded to the larger type, so that there is no unintentional data loss.

Answer (score 0):

The database stores the date in (about) millisecond resolution. When "12/12/2012 8:27:09 PM" is displayed, there is probably a millisecond part that is not displayed, but will throw off a comparison with a date that doesn't specify those milliseconds.

The ">" comparison will succeed because the stored date *is* higher than your specified date, precisely because of those milliseconds.